# JS window variables declaration and behavior

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have two global variables declared differently. I supposed that since both of them are properties of the window object, they should behave the same. But it is not. I can delete only one of them, that which was declared explicitly as a window property. That one which was declared by **var** operator cannot be deleted:

```
window.y1 = 'Y1';
"Y1"
var y2 = 'Y2';
undefined
y1;
"Y1"
y2;
"Y2"
window.y1;
"Y1"
window.y2;
"Y2"
delete window.y1;
true
delete window.y2;
false
```

It is not clear to me, why. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var`s on the global object are non-configurable, which means they cannot be deleted:

```js
var y2 = 'foo';
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'y2')
);
```

Behavior is as expected. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) says:

> Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.

On the other hand, explicitly assigning a property to an object *does* result in that property being configurable, by default:

```js
window.y2 = 'foo';
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'y2')
);
```